# Issue with csrf_token while using Flask and WTForms

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm trying to set up a basic "Contact" form for my website, which will basically take in values and then put them into a CSV file. The issue I'm having is that the entries cannot be validated cause they're missing a csrf_token?

Here's the relevant code from my app.py:

```
@app.route('/contact_end', methods=['POST'])
def handle_contact():
    form = ContactForm()
    print(form.name.data)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("yup")
        with open('data/messages.csv', 'a') as f:
            print("oh shit")
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow([form.name.data, form.email.data, form.message.data])
            print("waddup")

        return redirect(url_for('contact_handler.html'), name=form.name.data)
    print(form.errors)
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

It skips over the if statement as it never ends out printing the "yup", and instead it prints out the error:

> {'csrf_token': ['The CSRF token is missing.']}

The template that this connects to is:

```
{% extends "base_template.html" %}
    {% block title %}Contact us {% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    <p>Feel free to use the contact form below to send us any questions you might have.</p></br>
        <form action="/contact_end" method="post">
            {{ form.csrf_token }}
            <label>Your Name <input type="text" name="name"/></label></br>
            <label>Your Email <input type="text" name="email"/></label></br>
            <label>Your Name <textarea name="message"></textarea></label></br>
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
            <button type="reset">Clear</button>
        </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

I've tried messing with form.csrf_token and .hidden_tags(), but with no success.

As well, this is the initial part of app.py that brings you to the page in the first place, the one above is the endpoint for the form:

```
@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

Finally, here's my ContactForm class:

```
class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
    print("yep")
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[InputRequired()])
    email = EmailField('Email', validators=[InputRequired(), Email()])
    message = TextAreaField('Message', validators=[InputRequired()])
```

I've made sure to set my secret key, as well. Anyone have any idea why this isn't working? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to create the form instance in your `contact()` function:

```
@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    form = ContactForm()
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```